# how to notify about $interval end in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, timeout, intervals

I want to make custom animation in my web application, and i'm using $interval method to do some visual effects.
And all i want is to know, when that animation ends.

For example

```
var myInterval = $interval(function(){
    //do some staff
}, 10, 20);
```

How can i get notify about that interval ends? Except $timeout(fn, 200), of course.

And the second question is also about notifying, but in case, when i cancel that interval is other place manually by $interval.cancel(myInterval), can i get notified about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can broadcast an event by yourself when canceling the interval. Take a look at [$rootScope.$broadcast()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast).

Where you cancel the interval:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('Custom::Event');
```

Where you want to retrieve the broadcast:

```
$scope.$on('Custom::Event', function (e) { ... });
```

**Edit: Iterations**

If you want to send the broadcast after the last iteration, check the first parameter provided to the function for the $interval.

```
$interval(function (iteration) {

  // Do some stuff...

  // Broadcast after last iteration
  if (iteration === iterations - 1) {
    $scope.$broadcast('Interval::Finished');
  }
}, delay, iterations);
```

See: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wolosi/1/edit)

Comment: hm...looks good, but only for second case. 
What about first case, when i manually set count of iterations?

Answer (score 3):

For the first case, you can just do:

```
myInterval.then(function () { console.log("Finished."); } );
```

It isn't a good idea to count the number of iterations when Angular is already doing that for you.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q